# Does isolated storage contents survive an update?

Tags: vb.net, inno-setup, isolatedstorage, installshield-2010

If I write a license file to isolated storage in a vb.net winforms app, and the app then undergoes a minor update, does the license file get "carried over" somehow during the update?

Isolated storage seems to use the full version number as the lowest level directory name which makes me think it doesn't.

The license file is needed to allow full use of the app and I don't want users to have to re-enter their license code after an update.

Not sure how the update will be done yet - either Inno setup or Installshield LE.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a WinForm one, I advice you not to use IsolatedStorage, which is a little too restrictive and uncustomizable. The IsolatedStorage isn't overriden in Windows Phone and Metro apps but (if I remember well) is in Win Forms. To conclude, it would be better to use a file in another location (like AppData/Roaming/YourCoolAppName), and it has the advantage for you to know exactly where the data is stored.